# Let $K \subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set and let $f:K\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis

I am finding it hard to solve this problem.
Let $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set and let $f:K\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. Prove that the set 
$$\Gamma:=\{(x,y)\in K\times\mathbb{R}:y\in[0, f(x)]\}$$
is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.

Comment: Hint, try using Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: Hint: Show that it is closed and bounded. For boundedness note that $f(K)$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

$\Gamma$ is closed : indeed, let's suppose that there exists a sequence $(x_n, y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $\Gamma$, converging to a point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$. First, $x_n \in K$, so because $K$ is closed, $x \in K$. Moreover, you have $0 \leq y_n \leq f(x_n)$ for each $n$ : taking the limit, you get by continuity of $f$ that $0 \leq y \leq f(x)$. So $(x,y) \in \Gamma$, so $\Gamma$ is closed.

$\Gamma$ is bounded : indeed, $K$ is bounded because it is compact, so the first coordinate of every point of $\Gamma$ is uniformly bounded ; secondly, $f$ is bounded on $K$ because it is continuous and $K$ is compact, so the second coordinate of every point of $\Gamma$ is bounded (between $0$ and $\max_K f$). So $\Gamma$ is bounded.